# Set custom sizes for width and height in Tailwind

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I want to set A4 size (210 x 297 mm) in Tailwind. I guess what I'm looking for is something like below

```js
  theme: {
    extend: {
      spacing: {
        width: {
          a4: "210mm",
        },
        height: {
          a4: "297mm"
        }
      },
    },
```

```html
<div class="w-a4 h-a4">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

[Spacing](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-spacing) is kinda a group of sizes

> By default the spacing scale is inherited by the padding, margin, width, height, maxHeight, gap, inset, space, and translate core plugins.

So when you're register spacing like

```js
 theme: {
    extend: {
      spacing: {
        a4: '210mm',
      },
    },
```

You will be able to use `p-a4`, `m-a4`, `h-a4`, `w-a4` etc. All of them will have size of `210mm`

If you wish to split sizes, no need in `spacing` key - just pass `width` and `height`

```js
 theme: {
    extend: {
      width: {
         a4: '210mm',
      },
      height: {
        a4: '297mm',
      },
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

custom size（number）

custom is usually in .`w-{number}` and `.w-px` two type ，at number In terms of what rem do Relative unit，`px` Is the **absolute** unit of pixels 。In `rem`, each unit is **0.25rem**, or **1/4 of a font size**.

like this the classname like `w-1`

```html
<div class="w-1"></div>
```

```css
.w-1 { width: 1rem; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Per [docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/width#customizing-your-theme) You should have been written like this:

```js
spacing: {
  width: {
    'a4': "210mm",
  },
  height: {
    'a4': "297mm"
  }
},
```

Or using [Arbitrary values](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/width#arbitrary-values) If you don't want to extend.
If your using **vscode** install **Tailwind CSS IntelliSense** for autocompleting.